# Finding homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I asked a question earlier regarding finding a homeomorphism between
$$\Delta_{t}^n = \{ (t_0,...,t_n) : \Sigma (t_i)=1, 0 \leq t_i \leq 1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$ and $$\Delta_{x}^n = \{(x_1,...,x_n) : 0 \leq x_1 \leq...\leq x_n \leq 1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^n.$$ Here we consider the the subspace topology on the subset and the standard Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ respectively.

I have tried to construct it myself ever since but have failed every time. I found this : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex

There is no complete proof, but that is ok, what I really don't understand is his definition of $S_n$ under the section transformation between Barycentric and Cartesian coordinates, isn't this a function between $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$? Also how can I see if the restriction he describes is a homeomorphism? Or is only $S_n$ a homeomorphism here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious homeomorphism is
$$(t_0,\ldots,t_n)\mapsto(t_0,t_0+t_1,t_0+t_1+t_2,\ldots,t_0+t_1+\cdots+t_{n-1}).$$

The $S_n$ in the attached webpage is erroneous, as you say. Just
drop the last coordinate.

Comment: Thought so aswell, but didn't really see how this actually is an homeomorphism. Is it obvious that it is a bijection for instance?

Comment: Just write down an inverse. @Sodan

Comment: I think that $(x_1,...,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,x_2-x_1,...,x_n-x_{n-1},1-x_n)$ is a legit inverse function. I will try to prove the functions are continuous from the basic definition, I hope this does not get to messy?

Comment: @Sodan Continuity should prove no problem; we are just dealing with polynomials.

Comment: polynomials? What do you mean?

Comment: @Sodan you don't think that something like $x_2-x_1$ is a polynomial???

Comment: I see what you mean now.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how I can prove the continuity of the functions? I really see where to start from the basic definition.